# pytest mock exceptions for a class instantiation and method

Tags: python, pytest

I have following fixture.

```
import mod1
import pytest
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture()
def patched_mocked():
    with mock.patch('mod1.f1') as mocked_function:
        x_mock = mock.Mock(mod1.X)
        x_mock.producer = mock.Mock() # need to mock exception
        x_mock.producer.func2 = lambda: None # need to mock exception
        mocked_function.return_value = x_mock
        yield x_mock

def test_1(patched_mocked):
```

And here is the `mod1.py`:

```
class Y:
    def func2(self):
        raise Exception("Shouldn't be called")

class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.producer = Y()

    def func1(self):
        self.producer.func2()
```

I have a few test cases use the fixture above. Now I need to write two test cases for `Y.func2()` and `Y()` raise exception respectively. How to mock the exceptions?

---

I tried the following but it's not working.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def patched_mocked_exception():
    with mock.patch('mod1.f1') as mocked_function:
        x_mock = mock.Mock(mod1.X)
        x_mock.producer = mock.Mock()
        with mock.patch('mod1.f1.Y.func2', side_effect=Exception('mocked ex'):
            x_mock.producer.func2 = lambda: None
        mocked_function.return_value = x_mock
        yield x_mock
```

Comment: `side_effect` should work fine, but I don't understand what exactly you are going to mock. You reference `mod1.f1` and `mod1.f1.Y`, which is not in your function - can you show the complete example?

Comment: I just used your original fixture. And in the test case, I did `patched_mocked.func2.side_effect = Exception()` and it works.

Comment: So, it does work now? Or do you want it to do another way?

Comment: @ca9163d9 It would be great if you could write couple lines as an own-answer, I am afraid I didin't understand what happened here...